# Redirect all traffic from one domain

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, redirection

I have a server with a VM on it running. I'm now trying to redirect all traffic to the VM which uses a special domain.

Example:

```
domainA.example:1234 // don't redirect <br>
domainB.example:1234 // redirect to vm
```

The VM has it's own network IP so I tried to redirect the traffic using iptables

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst 172.16.0.2
```

The code above now redirects all traffic to the VM. I only want to redirect the traffic from one domain to the VM (`domainB.example`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `iptables` has no understanding of what a "domain-name" is.  You'd probably be better off by using a proxy on the parent web server that can proxy the connection to the VM.